# Delete all occurrences of an object with an id in an array - JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

how do I remove duplicate objects which has same id in an array of objects? I expect only object with id 1 for the below code.

This is my solution:

```js
let data = [{
    "selected": true,
    "id": 3,
    "ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup",
    "SupplierID": 1,
    "CategoryID": 2,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles",
    "UnitPrice": 10,
    "UnitsInStock": 13,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 70,
    "ReorderLevel": 25,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "Category": {
      "CategoryID": 2,
      "CategoryName": "Condiments",
      "Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    }
  },
  {
    "selected": true,
    "id": 3,
    "ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup",
    "SupplierID": 1,
    "CategoryID": 2,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles",
    "UnitPrice": 10,
    "UnitsInStock": 13,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 70,
    "ReorderLevel": 25,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "Category": {
      "CategoryID": 2,
      "CategoryName": "Condiments",
      "Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    }
  },
  {
    "selected": true,
    "id": 1,
    "ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup",
    "SupplierID": 1,
    "CategoryID": 2,
    "QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles",
    "UnitPrice": 10,
    "UnitsInStock": 13,
    "UnitsOnOrder": 70,
    "ReorderLevel": 25,
    "Discontinued": false,
    "Category": {
      "CategoryID": 2,
      "CategoryName": "Condiments",
      "Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"
    }
  }
]


let data1 = data.filter(item => {
  return _.isEqual(data.lastIndexOf(item.id), data.indexOf(item.id))
})

console.log(data1)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

It returns the same list. I expect an array with just id 1 object.

Please advice on a way to achieve this.

P.S: I can use lodash too.

Comment: I want to remove all occurrences. In the example, it should return an empty array.

Answer (score 1):

Will this lodash function help it combines all duplicates

`_.uniqBy(data,'id')`

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `object` to keep track of `id's` and it's `repetition count`, loop over array again and add it to final output only if it's count is `1`

```js
let data = [{"selected": true,"id": 3,"ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup","SupplierID": 1,"CategoryID": 2,"QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles","UnitPrice": 10,"UnitsInStock": 13,"UnitsOnOrder": 70,"ReorderLevel": 25,"Discontinued": false,"Category": {"CategoryID": 2,"CategoryName": "Condiments","Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"}},{"selected": true,"id": 3,"ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup","SupplierID": 1,"CategoryID": 2,"QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles","UnitPrice": 10,"UnitsInStock": 13,"UnitsOnOrder": 70,"ReorderLevel": 25,"Discontinued": false,"Category": {"CategoryID": 2,"CategoryName": "Condiments","Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"}}, {"selected": true,"id": 1,"ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup","SupplierID": 1,"CategoryID": 2,"QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles","UnitPrice": 10,"UnitsInStock": 13,"UnitsOnOrder": 70,"ReorderLevel": 25,"Discontinued": false,"Category": {"CategoryID": 2,"CategoryName": "Condiments","Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"}}]
let tracker = {}

data.forEach(({id}) => {
  tracker[id] = tracker[id] || 0
  tracker[id]++
})

const final = data.filter(({id}) => tracker[id] === 1 )

console.log(final)
```

Comment: I want to remove all occurrences. In the example, it should return an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a library and ES6 is perfectly capable at 0(n) runtime. Further, you may want to normalize objects inside the array by their IDs for faster lookup.

To demonstrate, I've added a third object with id: 4 to show this code:

```
let data = [
  {"selected": true,"id": 3,"ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup","SupplierID": 1,"CategoryID": 2,"QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles","UnitPrice": 10,"UnitsInStock": 13,"UnitsOnOrder": 70,"ReorderLevel": 25,"Discontinued": false,"Category": {"CategoryID": 2,"CategoryName": "Condiments","Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"}},
  {"selected": true,"id": 3,"ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup","SupplierID": 1,"CategoryID": 2,"QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles","UnitPrice": 10,"UnitsInStock": 13,"UnitsOnOrder": 70,"ReorderLevel": 25,"Discontinued": false,"Category": {"CategoryID": 2,"CategoryName": "Condiments","Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"}}, 
  {"selected": true,"id": 4,"ProductName": "Aniseed Syrup","SupplierID": 1,"CategoryID": 2,"QuantityPerUnit": "12 - 550 ml bottles","UnitPrice": 10,"UnitsInStock": 13,"UnitsOnOrder": 70,"ReorderLevel": 25,"Discontinued": false,"Category": {"CategoryID": 2,"CategoryName": "Condiments","Description": "Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings"}}]

const deduped = data.reduce( (acc, obj ) => {
  // restructure id from each object
  const {"id" : id}  = obj
  if ( acc[id] ) {
    return acc
  } else {
    return { ...acc, 
            [id]: obj
          }
  }
}, {})
```

The returned value in dedupe will be normalized by ID:

```
{ 3: 
   { selected: true,
     id: 3,
     ProductName: 'Aniseed Syrup',
     SupplierID: 1,
     CategoryID: 2,
     QuantityPerUnit: '12 - 550 ml bottles',
     UnitPrice: 10,
     UnitsInStock: 13,
     UnitsOnOrder: 70,
     ReorderLevel: 25,
     Discontinued: false,
     Category: 
      { CategoryID: 2,
        CategoryName: 'Condiments',
        Description: 'Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings' } },
  4: 
   { selected: true,
     id: 4,
     ProductName: 'Aniseed Syrup',
     SupplierID: 1,
     CategoryID: 2,
     QuantityPerUnit: '12 - 550 ml bottles',
     UnitPrice: 10,
     UnitsInStock: 13,
     UnitsOnOrder: 70,
     ReorderLevel: 25,
     Discontinued: false,
     Category: 
      { CategoryID: 2,
        CategoryName: 'Condiments',
        Description: 'Sweet and savory sauces, relishes, spreads, and seasonings' } } }
```